# How do I change user's sign in method without changing UID in Firebase Auth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to provide a way that users can change their sign in method in my App using Firebase Auth.

For example, if previously a user signed up using Email and Password, then he/she wants to switch to Facebook or Google Sign in method. Then how do I do this without changing the user's UID ?

Probably something like:

```
firebase.auth()
.signInWithEmailAndPassword('you@domain.com', 'password')
.then((userCredential) {
        userCredential.user.updateSignInMethod(method: facebook)
        .then((userData) => loginWithFacebookProcedure());
    })
```

Is it possible? If yes, how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct ability to "switch" authentication providers with Firebase Authentication.  Once an account signs up with a provider (such as email/password), that option will always be available to the user of that account.

What you can do instead is [link additional providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) to an existing account, which will allow the user to authenticate using any of the providers linked to that account.  Until you [unlink](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#unlink-an-auth-provider-from-a-user-account) them.

So, if you really want to "switch", you will actually have to link to another provider, then unlink the old provider. But that seems like a waste of effort when you can simply retain all of the linked providers for the user to choose from.